# Not able to select Kendo UI + Angular JS dropdown list python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am not able to select drop-down option..

Sampe Dropdown : **https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/angular**

I wanted to select 'STATIC DAT' as a 'Austria' sung selenium python.

I am able to click on drop-down and all menus are visible but not able to select any option.

Sample code I rried:

```
        xpath = r'/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span[1]/span/span[2]'
        element_inst = web_driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        # Click dropdown list
        psu.perform_action(web_driver, element_inst, 'click')
        # Select option
        web_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Austria']").click()
```

Is there any solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following sample.

```
dropdown = web_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown']//span[text()='Albania']") // we depend on default country in list
dropdown.click() // trigger the dropdown

country = web_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='k-list-scroller']/ul/li[text()='Austria']")
country.click() // select the country
```

or try just using the 'select' tag (not sure it will work due display: none)

```
selectCountry = web_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='Austria']")
selectCountry.click();
```

if element cannot be selected by the normal way, try with jsclick

```
web_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", selectCountry)
```

Comment: Hi When I tried second approach I am getting error ```Error : Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated```

Comment: added jsclick example